# Returning an image cached image field in a Drupal 7 node template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have attached icons to taxonomy terms and referenced the term in the node:

`field_accreditation_icon` is the field on the taxonomy term. `field_accreditation` is the field on the node.

Placing this in node.tpl.php displays the correct icon:

```
  <?php
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($node->field_accreditation['und'][0]['tid']);
    $result = field_view_field('taxonomy_term',$term,'field_accreditation_icon');
    echo render($result);
  ?>
```

How would I render the icon as the ImageCache preset 'medium'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the uri for that image then create image url with theme,

```
<?php
// $img_uri will be the image uri value getting from database
print '<img src="'.image_style_url("medium", $img_uri).'" />';
?>
```

**image uri** can be get by using `taxonomy_term_load($tid);`

Comment: Thanks much for your help JSunny. I wasn't proficient enough to get your code to work, so I just did what I know; I built a View with a contextual filter. This worked perfectly for my needs.